# Time Consumption of FlushViewOfFile (Windows) and msync(Linux)

Tags: c++, windows, linux

We are interested in the time consumption of [`FlushViewOfFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-flushviewoffile) and `msync`. Quoting the [`UnmapViewOfFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-unmapviewoffile) documentation:

> To minimize the risk of data loss in the event of a power failure or a system crash, applications should explicitly flush modified pages using the `FlushViewOfFile` function.

Are `FlushViewOfFile()` and `msync()` expensive operations? The reason we are asking is that in our application, we may not need to minimize the risk of data loss in the event of a system crash.

Thank you,

Comment: `FlushViewOfFile` blocks proportional to the amount of pages that you have modified. `msync` is more complicated insofar as it can be used syncronously and asynchronously, and insofar as the Linux documentation lies about what madvise/msync do, at least in async mode (you'll fall off your chair if you read the comments in the kernel sources).

Comment: @Damon, How do you determine the amount of pages that you have modified using the Windows C/C++ API? We are using the Windows memory mapped file in read-only mode? Should FlushViewOfFile be used if you are using the Windows memory mapped file in a read mode. As for Linux, we are planning to use msync in the synchronous. How long does synchronous msync block for? Thank you for your excellent comment.

Comment: In read-only mode, `FlushViewOfFile` is not really needed and will take zero time. There is nothing to flush if you cannot have modified a thing.

Comment: @Damon, Thank you for very useful answer. For Linux, I wondering whether we really need to cal msync synchronons before munmap(MapPtr, mappedlength)? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Frank: munmap will sync all changes to disk (no msync needed), but since you map read-only, it will just discard the mapping, nothing else.

Comment: @Damon. Thank you for your answer about Linux munmap and msync.

Comment: @Frank about determine the amount of pages... the page size on Windows is 4096, basically, for every 4096:th byte range you touch, you have one corresponding page that will need to be flush to disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are expensive in the sense that they will move the cached file from memory to disk. Generally you use memory mapped files to avoid doing that!  The normal strategy is to flush as infrequently as your program requirements allow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just accepted your answer. We are using memory mapped files in Windows and Linux. We saw some sample code where FlushViewOfFile() was called just before UnMapOfView(). Are you suggesting that FlushViewOfFiles need not be called before every invocation of UnMapViewOfFile? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Frank That's right, you don't need to flush at all if you don't want to. You can let the system do it. If you aren't concerned about robustness across system power failure then not flushing gives the best performance.

Comment: @Devid Heffernan, Thank you for your reply. Your answer was very helpful.