# Strategy for asynchronously flushing view of file to disk

Tags: windows, winapi

I am writing an application that maps a file into memory to make some information resilient to failures (crash, power outage, etc). I know that the idea is to flush [as infrequently as allowable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964838/time-consumption-of-flushviewoffile-windows-and-msynclinux), but to Do Things Right, and considering the goal, it seems to me that I should essentially flush to disk whenever the data has changed.

All the mapped data fits into a single page. I have a burst usage pattern (nothing happens for a looong time, then all of a sudden you'd modify the information ~20 times in a row). For this reason, I'm hesitant about `FlushViewOfFile`, since it seems to be synchronous. Flushing at every hit on a burst would seem to be inefficient.

Is there not a way I can tell Windows to flush pages the next time it has an idle cycle, and without having me wait until it does it?

Comment: Why not just cache the burst data into a local buffer first, then copy the final buffer to the view when ready and flush it?  That way you are hitting the view only once.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, the main problem is to decide when to flush. Clients can touch all or some of the data at their convenience, but will generally get all they want in a short amount of time. I could start a timer and say "flush the file once it's been one second without activity" but I was wondering if there was a simpler option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that there is a function in Windows for that. `FlushViewOfFile` is what you have to work with. You're going to have to think of a 'scheduler' for your program that matches your use-case/profile. Something like starting a short timer after each hit, which resets if there is another hit and if it expires flushes the page, and one long timer which if it expires flushes the page despite still being in a burst would probably work nicely for you. In any case, you'll need to profile what the usage will be and have the program act accordingly.